# Formula to increment letter/number values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Below, is a sample data table.

I am trying to create a formula to generate the values in column B.

This is what I am trying to do but am having trouble incrementing the number: `If(A3=A2,B2,B2+1)`

[image: sample table]

Comment: "AMZ0001" is not a number, so you can't easily "add" to it.

Answer (score 4):

In **B1** enter:

```
 1
```

In **B2** enter:

```
 =IF(A1=A2,B1,B1+1)
```

and copy down.  Finally format the cells in column **B** with a Custom Format of `"AMZ"0000`like:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

An alternative approach is to use column **C** as a "*helper*".  Put **1** in **C1** and in **C2**:

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1,C1+1)
```

and copy down.  Then in **B1**:

```
="AMZ" & TEXT(C1,"0000")
```

and copy down.  This will put "real" material into column **B** rather than formatted integers:

[image]

Comment: @JChooks  You are quite welcome!

Comment: @ScottCraner  You are correct! ..................see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Cool.  You could also always put `AMZ0001` in B1 then in B2: `=IF(A1=A2,B1,"AMZ" & TEXT(RIGHT(B1,4)+1,"0000"))` and skip the helper.

Comment: @ScottCraner ..................Cooler Still !! .....................

Comment: @ScottCraner is so cool he's ICE COLD